# T-SQL - Merge two tables without create temp table

Tags: sql, t-sql, merge

[The prefer result i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZJwJ.jpg) I have those 2 T-SQL queries:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, AL.FECHA, 103) AS [DATE], 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, AL.HORA, 108) AS [HOUR], 
    SUM(CAST(AL.TOTALNETO AS money)) AS [AMOUNT]
FROM
    ALBVENTACAB AL
WHERE 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, AL.FECHA, 103) = '10/09/2020' 
    -- AND CONVERT(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 103) AND
    AND CONVERT(nvarchar, AL.HORA, 108) BETWEEN (SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, AL.HORA, 108)) AND CONVERT(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 108)
GROUP BY 
    AL.FECHA, AL.HORA
ORDER BY 
    AL.FECHA

SELECT 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, AL.FECHA, 103) AS [DATE], 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, AL.HORA, 108) AS [HOUR], 
    SUM(CAST(AL.TOTALNETO AS money)) AS [AMOUNT]
FROM 
    ALBVENTACAB AL
WHERE 
    FECHA = CAST(DATEADD(DD, -7, GETDATE()) AS date) 
    AND CONVERT(nvarchar, AL.HORA, 108) BETWEEN (SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, AL.HORA, 108)) AND CONVERT(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 108)
GROUP BY 
    AL.FECHA, AL.HORA
ORDER BY 
    AL.FECHA
```

Individually, their results are correct. I want to create a result as shown in the screenshot.

I tried to create a CTE, but that didn't work. What is the proper way?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean a result like an image? Are you not simply after a `UNION ALL`? `MERGE` as a operation in SQL, is *very* different; it's a "upsert" (an `UPDATE` and `INSERT`).

Comment: I forgot to upload an image with the result I want to achieve. Each query returns 3 columns. Date hour and amount. I want a result like Date hour amount Date hour amount

Comment: As a separate note: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: Consider: Inserting the word "UNION" or "UNION ALL" between the two queries and eliminate the order by on first query.  `UNION` will combine two data sets provided the values selected are the same type and # removing duplicates.  `UNION ALL` will not remove the duplicates.  IF you're after the same number of rows and not adding columns... `UNION` Will combine the two datasets.

Comment: Are you asking how to combine two unrelated sets of rows side-by-side? You can add a [`Row_Number`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) column to each query and then use `inner join` to match rows. (Or `outer join` if you are not guaranteed to have the same number of rows from each query.)

Answer (score 0):

First, the query I think you're looking for is something like this.  The Friday date (@fecha) was removed to a variable of type DATE.  Instead of 2 query, 1 for the week, and 1 for the particular Friday, it's now 1 query.  The friday sales are broken out using conditional aggregation into a new column called [FECHA_AMOUNT].  Note: this only works if the variable @fecha falls within the last 7 days.

```
declare @fecha          date='20201009';

SELECT 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, AL.FECHA, 103) AS [DATE], 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, AL.HORA, 108) AS [HOUR], 
    SUM(CAST(AL.TOTALNETO AS money)) AS [AMOUNT],
    SUM(case when cast(AL.FECHA as date)=@fecha then CAST(AL.TOTALNETO AS money) 
             else cast(0 as money) end) AS [FECHA_AMOUNT]
FROM 
    ALBVENTACAB AL
WHERE 
    FECHA = CAST(DATEADD(DD, -7, GETDATE()) AS date) 
    AND CONVERT(nvarchar, AL.HORA, 108) BETWEEN (SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, AL.HORA, 108)) 
    AND CONVERT(nvarchar, GETDATE(), 108)
GROUP BY 
    AL.FECHA, AL.HORA
ORDER BY 
    AL.FECHA;
```

Finally, as note in the comments.  When converting it's always good to use lengths.  Also, the money data type is not considered ideal.  Fwiw